# C++ Variable unexpectedly overwritten

Tags: c++, arduino

I just don't get it. I have two "main variables" `address` and `parameters`.
`address` is a const char and `parameters` is a string (char array) which is getting filled with information.

Now the very weird thing (at least for me): After adding the timestamp to `parameters`, `address` is cleared!

Does someone have an idea why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



void setOnlineStatus(char deviceName[30], bool deviceStatus, const char outputContent[50], int value, const char functionName[30], bool onlineRequestImmediately=true) {

    const char address[128]= "https://api.arduino.myAddress.com";
    char parameters[512] = "?secret=w2q3oifin23c&deviceName=";


cout << "Address: ";
cout << address << endl;

cout << "Parameters: ";
cout << parameters << endl;


    strcat(parameters, deviceName);// +"&status="+deviceStatus+"&value="+value+"&time="+getTimestamp()+"&functionName="+functionName;
    strcat(parameters, "&status=");

    char tempDeviceStatus[1];
    sprintf(tempDeviceStatus, "%d", deviceStatus);
    strcat(parameters, tempDeviceStatus);

cout << "Address01: ";
cout << address << endl;

    strcat(parameters, "&value=");
    char tempValue[3];
    sprintf(tempValue, "%d", (int) value);
    strcat(parameters, tempValue);

cout << "Address02: ";
cout << address << endl;


    strcat(parameters, "&functionName=");
    strcat(parameters, functionName);


cout << "Address03: ";
cout << address << endl;

    strcat(parameters, "&time=");
    char tempTimestamp[10];
    sprintf(tempTimestamp, "%d", 1234567890);
    strcat(parameters, tempTimestamp); // this doesn't work neither: strcat(parameters, "1234567890");

cout << "Address04: ";
cout << address << endl; // output is empty!


    strcat(parameters, "&message=");
    strcat(parameters, outputContent);


cout << "Address05: ";
cout << address << endl; // output is empty!

cout << "Parameters: ";
cout << parameters << endl;

  }




int main()
{
    setOnlineStatus("testControl1", 1, "controlTurnedOff", 201, "toggleFans()");
}
```

That's the output:

```
Address: https://api.arduino.myAddress.com
Parameters: ?secret=w2q3oifin23c&deviceName=
Address01: https://api.arduino.myAddress.com
Address02: https://api.arduino.myAddress.com
Address03: https://api.arduino.myAddress.com
Address04: 
Address05: 
Parameters: ?secret=w2q3oifin23c&deviceName=testControl1&status=1&value=201&functionName=toggleFans()&time=1234567890&message=controlTurnedOff
```

Comment: Where do you check if you write out of bounds? Why do you use C strings instead of `std::string`. This would fix your problem.

Comment: This is what happens when you write C code and only pretend that it's C++. Specifically, this is what happens when you use fixed-size `char` arrays, instead of `std::string`s, and use legacy C library functions like `strcat`, `sprintf`. It's very easy to make one of them too small, and one of your `char` buffers is too small, and you scribble over innocent memory, while writing to it. It will take you some time to find which one it is, unless someone takes pity and points it out to you. And after that, perhaps you will want to consider actually writing C++, instead of C?

Comment: you could save yourself a lot of grief by using std::string instead of C-style char arrays

Comment: You overflow buffer of `tempDeviceStatus` .  Also even using sprintf instead of all those strcats would be a whole lot better

Comment: Because I'm actually on an Arduino and because of the limited memory I don't want to use `string` class there. I learned not to use it there.

Comment: Following that same line of (mis)reasoning, then why are you using C++ at all?

Comment: Then you should use `strncat` and `snprintf`. Why do you create a char array of length 1: `char tempDeviceStatus[1];`? That's one char. That should probably be `char tempDeviceStatus[2];`

Comment: @M.M: I don't see the error? Why is there an overflow, how big should `tempDeviceStatus` be if 2 is not enough?

Comment: @alve89 it has size 1, not 2

Comment: @Eljay the arduino comes with this programming language (which is some kind of subset of C++) , there is not much option

Comment: @M.M: Still, even with `char tempDeviceStatus[2];` I have an empty output later at address04.

Comment: Why do you think that `std::string` uses more memory than a C string? With C strings you have to remember the current size. You have to add error handling for cases where the C strings get to long. You are allocating memory for 512 chars to avoid std::string and to save memory?

Comment: From my point of view that's the point: An Arduino has very limited memory so I need to control that and cannot allow everything. That's what I learned... It's interesting that you say the opposite? I am a newbie so I don't know it better. :-(

Comment: @ThomasSablik The `std::string` will use memory from the free store whereas a char array uses automatic storage,  so if the system has a small (or nonexistent) free store but has enough automatic storage for the task, then the automatic storage may be preferable

Comment: @M.M. IMHO this is optimization and should only be done if there is a bottleneck. OP is a beginner and doesn't write time or memory critical applications. Arduino provides the string class and it is okay to use it to start learning.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik -- The reasons for not using Strings on an Arduino are well documented.  It's a pretty big deal int he Arduino world.  It has to do with there not being any garbage collection to clean up the heap and continued use of strings that change sizes eventually leads to a crash once the heap is so full of holes that it can't find room to store the new string.  Arduino doesn't deal well with dynamic allocation if you aren't extremely careful.  If you aren't familiar with the limitations of the Arduino platform then perhaps you should pull back a little on Arduino questions.

Comment: There is also the issue of the additional code overhead involved on such tiny microcontrollers.

Comment: @Delta_G I started learning C++ with a simple Hello World program and I learned step by step. Usage of C strings can be complex. Starting with a String class makes it easier.

Comment: OK.  But they also lead to unstable code and that's well documented.  So when a user wants to try to learn to avoid them that's a great next step.  And we shouldn't discourage it.  And we certainly shouldn't claim that it is somehow better.  Sure the user reserves enough memory for the largest string possible, but Arduino is a one program machine.  So what exactly are they going to use the saved memory for if there is a possibility later that they might need it for a larger string?  In that case what's the harm in having it reserved already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pile of buffers and strcats and stuff is waaaaaay more complicated than it needs to be

Instead you can do this:

```
char parameters[512];
int result = snprintf(parameters, sizeof parameters,
     "?secret=w2q3oifin23c"
     "&deviceName=%s"
     "&status=%d"
     "&value=%d"
     "&functionName=%s"
     "&time=%d"
     "&message=%s",
    deviceName, (int)deviceStatus, value, functionName, 1234567890, outputContent);

if ( result < 0 || result >= sizeof parameters )
     // ...handle error or overflow
```

In the original code you overflow `tempDeviceStatus` which has size 1 but you write two characters to it (0 or 1 plus a null terminator) and you also overflow `tempValue`

Comment: I will try your code but please have a look at this: https://www.onlinegdb.com/Hkg5ohB2YL -> I already increased `tempDeviceStatus` to 2 and the problem is still the same.

Comment: @alve89 you also overflow `tempValue`

Comment: Alright, I always forgot the null terminator. Damn. Many thanks to you! And thanks for your code example, I will study that, I never used that function before.

Comment: Also, don't forget to URL-encode those querystring parameters